# Python bleak and pyttsx3 can't be used in the same script

Tags: multithreading, incompatibility

## Using Python 3.9

import bleak

import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

## OSError: [WinError -2147417850] Cannot change thread mode after it is set

Comment: I’ve found a temporary “workaround” for this problem. It’s not elegant but works for me in this case. I separated the Bluetooth code from the voice synthesis code and converted the Bluetooth code into an EXE file. I then call it at the appropriate point in the main code. The EXE file blocks the program in the main code until it finishes reading the Bluetooth instrument. The main code then proceeds as normal.